# Как получить значение jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<span class="num" id="total-guest-count">35</span>
```

Как в jquery вывести 35 в console.log ?

Comment: console.log($('#total-guest-count').text())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/fcqe8hya/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log($("#total-guest-count").text());
});
```

Comment: если на станице будет несколько элементов с классом "num" - он выведет не совсем искомое.

Comment: и да, и нет.
он не выдаст скорей всего ничего, так как вернет массив.
можно сказать что правильней использовать id но это дело вкуса, на практике, ид также бывает не уникальным.
при этом мой ответ полностью отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8coae4us/1/ - кажется js не согласен с тем, что вернет ничего или массив)

Comment: вы правы, он явно лучше, чем я о нём думал. :)